# Zip in memory and encode with base64

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, svg, zip, base64

I want to zip a SVG file in memory and encode it with base64 (I want to save the zipped/base64 SVG in a XML file).

This is what I have (but I am open to everything):

```
byte[] svg = File.ReadAllBytes("test.SVG");
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{  
    using (Package pkg = Package.Open(ms, FileMode.Create)) 
    {
        PackagePart part = pkg.CreatePart(new Uri("/test.SVG", UriKind.Relative), "image/svg+xml", CompressionOption.Normal);  
        using (Stream strm = part.GetStream()) 
        {  
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strm)) 
            {  
                sw.Write(svg);
            }

            byte[] b = ReadToEnd(part.GetStream());
            return Convert.ToBase64String(b);
        }
    }
}
```

It convert something to base64 but that is not my file since it is only a few characters long.

Comment: `ReadToEnd(part.GetStream())` looks wrong.

Comment: That is a function I left out since it is a little long. It copies a stream to a byte array. But I copied it from the net and I think it is fine.

Comment: I expect a base64 string of a 50kb file longer than 13 characters :)

Comment: Ahh, I see the confusion with my initial comment: the issue likely isn't the `ReadToEnd`, but rather what is being passed (which is what I was trying to point out). You want to pass the *final output stream* after it has been *flushed* (or rather, all streams into it have been flushed) and *reset*. If a stream is read before it is flushed ("fully written") - or is read when not seek'ed to the start - then the data obtained may be incomplete.

Comment: (That line also looks problematic because it is access `GetStream` *again*, instead of using `strm`.)

Comment: @user2246674: The `StreamWriter` is disposed by the `using`, which closes the `StreamWriter` and the underlying stream, flushing before they're closed of course. So calling `GetStrm` again isn't a problem. The problem is much deeper. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not seeking the stream to the beginning. Easiest fix is to use `ToArray` right before disposing `MemoryStream`:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  // Whatever manipulations with stream you need goes here.
  ...
  ms.Close(); // guarantees to commit all changes, 
              // safe to do as `ToArray` work on disposed stream
  return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArrray());
}
```

Comment: If I catch that byte array and write it to a zip before encoding, then there are 2 files in that zip: content_types.xml and test.svg, but that is only 1 kB big and is not the original image.

Comment: @juergend are you sure test.svg file is the right one (what is `svg.Length`?) Also why you are using `StreamWriter` to save bytes instead of `Stream.Write` OR reaging SVG as string and writing it with `StreamWriter.Write(string)`?  - writing bytes with StreamWriter loks wrong...

Comment: +1. Exactly. And, yes, the `StreamWriter` is the reason he's not getting much data. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems with your code.

Most importantly, you're opening a `StreamWriter` to write binary data. You have:

```
byte[] svg;

...

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(...))
{
    sw.Write(svg);
}
```

`StreamWriter` is used to write *text*. The call you have ends up resolving to `TextWriter.Write(object)`. The result is as if you had called:

```
sw.Write(svg.ToString());
```

Which will output the name of the class (`"System.Byte[]"`). That's why what you're getting is 13 bytes long. It also points to another problem (see below).

So the first thing you need to do is ditch the `StreamWriter` and have:

```
    using (Stream strm = part.GetStream()) 
    {  
        strm.Write(svg, 0, svg.Length)
    }
```

That, at least, will write the data you want to the stream.

Now, as for reading, you have a problem. You probably can then write:

```
        strm.Flush();
        strm.Position = 0;
        byte[] b = ReadToEnd(part.GetStream());
        return Convert.ToBase64String(b);
```

I don't know what your `ReadToEnd` method does. Perhaps it positions the stream and reads everything. But that's not going to give you what you want, which is the other problem I alluded to.

The stream returned by `part.GetStream` overrides the `Read` method and *decompresses the data*. So the byte array you get back will be the same as the original `svg` array that you wrote.

Looking at the Package API, I don't see a method that will give you the compressed data stream for a particular part.

In short, I think you need to write the entire package, convert *that* to base-64, and return it, as shown in [Alexei's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19037614/56778).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Brought me a step further. The zip itself (I do a `File.WriteAllBytes("tst.zip", b);` is corrupt though.

Comment: @juergend: did you read the entire answer? The "file" you get by calling `ReadToEnd` is not going to be a valid zip file. You have to write the entire package. You cannot extract an individual part.